# UITableView reloaddata doesn't reload immediately

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to work with online data in my iPhone app. But I'm getting mad because of this:

I have object for downloading data with NSURLConnection. Method starting the work with connection (and other stuff) in separate thread - `[ NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector( doConnectionInNewThread ) toTarget: self withObject: nil ];`

When data are loaded (connectionDidFinishLoading) I give them to my viewController. This all stuff works fine. When I use breakpoints or NSLog I have the data ready to show in UITableView. When I call reloadData, nothing happens immediately. It reloads data after maybe 2 seconds (`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is called after this delay).

BUT when I slide the tableView, it reloads data immediately. So the connection and so on works fine but it just doesn't reload the data. Why? I thought it could be due to blocked mainThread by URLConnection. But now I use it in separate thread and it is still the same...

Answer (score 2):

Are you accessing your table view in the detached thread?

Make sure to update the UI on the main thread using:

-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:

Comment: hm. So now I run my object function with connection stuff normally (in no detached thread) but when I get all needed data I call "-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:" to inform my viewController to reloadData and it's working perfectly. 

Thank you! 

Whats the trick? The name says something like "do this on mainThread with no patience". So it stops the previous URLConnection or what?

Comment: Accessing UI state machine on a non main thread is generally not supported. In particular reloadData marks the table view as needing display to reload the data (ie reloading data is lazy). Since you're not on the main thread, display scheduling is likely incorrect.

Comment: You also MUST NOT be manipulating the same collection (mutable array or dictionary) you use when displaying the data from your background thread, at least not without appropriate locking.  You can't add objects to an NSMutableArray or NSMutableDictionary from one thread while reading from it on another.

Answer (score 0):

Your `tableView.reloadData` function probably doesn't run in main thread so you should use `tableview.reloadData()` in `DispatchQueue.main.async` to run that in the main thread.

example:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  tableview.reloadData()
}
```